# Should I use memcache?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, kmz

My code produces a [zip file](http://www.montao.com.br/montaolist.kmz) from Google App Engine for loading in a browser ie 10 KB < size < 1000 KB and I wonder if I can use memcache here or if the file is too large or already cached. I already use both memcache and set the cache control when generating the actual file first.

```
class KMZHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def add_file(self, zip_file, url, file_name):
        """Fetch url, and add content as file_name to the zip file."""
        result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        if not result.content:
            return
        zip_file.writestr(file_name, result.content)

    def get(self):
        """Attempt to create a zip file."""
        # you could set 'count' like this:
        # count = int(self.request.get('count', 1000))

        zipstream = StringIO.StringIO()
        zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zipstream, "w")

        # repeat this for every URL that should be added to the zipfile
        url = 'http://www.koolbusiness.com/list.kml'
        self.add_file(zip_file, url, "list.kml")

        # we have finished with the zip so package it up and write the directory
        zip_file.close()

        # set the headers...

        self.response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public,max-age=%s" % 86400
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] ='application/zip'
        self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="list.kmz"'

        # create and return the output stream
        zipstream.seek(0)
        self.response.out.write(zipstream.read())
        zipstream.close()
```

Here is the part that uses memcache and creates the actual file:

```
class KMLHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
 def get(self):   
    self.response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "public,max-age=%s" % 86400
    start=datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(days=20)
    count = int(self.request.get('count')) if not self.request.get('count')=='' else 1000        
    from google.appengine.api import memcache
    memcache_key = "ads"
    data = memcache.get(memcache_key)
    if data is None:
      a= Ad.all().filter("modified >", start).filter("url IN", ['www.koolbusiness.com']).filter("published =", True).order("-modified").fetch(count)
      memcache.set("ads", a)  
    else:
      a = data
    dispatch='templates/kml.html'
    template_values = {'a': a , 'request':self.request,}
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), dispatch)
    output = template.render(path, template_values)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'
    self.response.headers['Content-Length'] = len(output)
    self.response.out.write(output)
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: Should we know how large your file actually is? How should be give a recommendation if you don't provide the most obvious information about the size of the files?

Comment: I linked to the zip file whose size may vary. It is a KMZ file for loading in a browser and I thought maybe you knew the max value for files in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is [under 1mb](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/overview.html#Quotas_and_Limits), and it does not change for each request, then memcaching the KMZ would likely reduce resource usage.

The KMZ file is not already in memcache, though it could be in a front-end cache.  You are memcaching the results from the query when you generate the KML (see Nick's blog for a description of [how to memcache entities](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching)), but the cache does not take different values of `count` or `start` into account.  Tf that is not important, you might also consider directly memcaching the KML (or KMZ) file;  if it *is* important you ned to fix the caching strategy.

Comment: That's great to know Robert. Thank you for the informative answer.